# Expression for path to a property of element of enumerable type property

Tags: c#, expression

I am writing a method which needs to know the path to a nested property from a source object. I am thinking of taking an `Expression<Func<T, object>>`. My method signature would look like this.

```
public bool DetailsQueried<T>(IResolverContext ctx, Expression<Func<T,object>>propertyPath)
```

I am using it as below

```
Analyzer.DetailsQueried<PaginatedRecords>(ctx, page => page.PageCount)
```

Now, I want to navigate to a nested property which is part of items of an enumerable property on the source type.

```
Analyzer.DetailsQueried<PaginatedRecords>(ctx, page => page.Records[0].Name)
```

As you can see above, the index 0 is irrelevant above, I just wanted to specify the Name property.What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why is the index irrelevant? The name at index 0 could be different from the name at index 1.

Comment: what do you actually do in `DetailsQueried` ? you return a bool? why? why would you call `Analyzer.DetailsQueried<PaginatedRecords>` instead of `Analyzer.DetailsQueried<Record>` in the last line?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry that it is not really obvious from the way I described it. I am writing a method to check a graphql query, if certain nested property of an object has been queried. Therefore, in my use-case, the index is not relevant.

Comment: what type are the items in `page.Records` ?

Comment: @MongZhu We can assume it is of type Record for now, which has a Name property :).

Comment: There is no such thing as "best way" in programming in general. It all depends on context. Some ways of programming are better than others in different situations. Please tell us in what context you are asking this question. What is it you are exactly trying to achieve? For more information when it comes to asking questions, please refer to [MCVE].

Comment: "We can assume it is of type Record for now" ok, then you could call the method like this: `Analyzer.DetailsQueried<Record>(ctx, rec => rec.Name)`, or does the inner workings of `DetailsQueried` prevent you from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can go with Fluen API usage here.
As example - you can use [EF Fuluent API](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx)

For you specific case, it can be something like:

```
public class Analyzer<T>
{
    public bool DetailsQueried(IResolverContext ctx, Expression<Func<T, object>> simpleProperty) => true;
    public Analyzer<TItem> DetailsQueried<TItem>(IResolverContext ctx, Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TItem>>> simpleProperty) => new Analyzer<TItem>();
}
```

and used as:

```
var analyzer = new Analyzer<PaginatedRecords>();
analyzer
    .DetailsQueried(ctx, outer => outer.Records)
    .DetailsQueried(ctx, inner => inner.Name);
```